# Can someone tell me how to make my website fit larger screen sizes? 1920x1080

Tags: css, reactjs

So I've just decided to apply for some junior positions only to realize that my portfolio website doesn't work on larger screen sizes as it looks too stretched.

After applying for a lot of jobs, can someone please suggest what I can do to fix it?
Should I use media queries?

I built it on a laptop so it was hard to see what it would look like on larger screens.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code for my header :

```css
$header-color: rgb(31 33 34 / 95%);
$primary-color: rgba(12, 12, 12, 0.95);
$secondary-color: rgb(60 255 255);
$base-color: #fafafa;
$heading: 3rem;
$sub-heading: 2rem;
$font-size: .9rem;
$font-color: #fff;

// Dark Mode

#light .nav-bar {
    background-color: rgb(192, 165, 165);
}

#light .home {
    background-color: rgb(218, 186, 186);
}

#light .home h1 {
    color: rgb(27, 26, 26);
}

#light .home .word {
    color: rgb(241 60 152);
}

#light .about {
    background-color: rgb(218, 186, 186);
}

#light .projects-container {
    background-color: rgb(218, 186, 186);
}
#light .contact {
    background-color: rgb(218, 186, 186);
}
#light .description {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
#light .lang-name {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
#light h2 {
    color: $primary-color;
}
#light .heading {
    background-color: rgb(218, 186, 186);
}
#light h3 {
    color: black;
}
#light p {
    color: black;
}
#light a {
    color: black;
}
#light .nav-item-resume a {
    color: yellow;
}

#dark {
    background-color: $primary-color;
}


.nav-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 4rem;
    background-color: rgb(144, 187, 187);
    background-color: $header-color;
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.navigation {
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

a {
    list-style: none;
    color: $base-color;
    font-size: $font-size;
    text-decoration: none;
}


a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: $secondary-color;
    transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

.switch {
    padding-left: .2rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
   gap: .2rem;

    label {
        color: white;
    }
    font-size: .5rem;
    font-style: italic;
}

.nav-item-resume a {
    color: yellow;
}

// Breakpoints

// 500 - 400px

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    a {
        list-style: none;
        color: $base-color;
        font-size: .7rem;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    label {
        color: white;
        font-size: .5rem;
    }

    .home h1 {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    .lrgbtn-container {

        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        min-height: 10vh;
    
        button {
            min-width: 200px;
            min-height: 50px;
            border: none;
            background-color: rgba(26, 25, 25, 0.95);
            color: #fff;
            border-radius: 4px;
            transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
            font-size: 1rem;
            outline: none;
            border: 3px solid rgb(83, 235, 235);
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        
    }

    .description {
        padding: 20px 0;
        font-size: .7rem;
        color: $font-color;
        max-width: 50%;
        text-align: start;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }

    .skills-name img {
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
    }
    
    h2 {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 2rem;
        color: rgb(60, 255, 255);
    }

    .smlbtn-container {

        button {
            width: 80px;
            height: 40px;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            background-color: rgba(26, 25, 25, 0.95);
            border: 3px solid rgb(83, 235, 235);
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgb(144, 187, 187);
            transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
            font-size: .8rem;
            outline: none;
        }
    } 

    .contact-msg {
        padding: 50px;
        font-size: 0.7rem;
    }

    .navigation {
        display: flex;
        gap: 10px;
    }

    .nav-bar {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        min-width: 100vw;
        min-height: 4rem;
        background-color: rgb(144, 187, 187);
        background-color: $header-color;
        backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1000;
        gap: 3rem;
    }

    .skills-name img {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
    }

    .skills-name {
        font-size: small;
    }




  }

  // 1000px

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    p {
        font-size: .8rem;
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
}

  // 850px

@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
    .projects-container {
        max-width: 100vw;
        min-height: 50vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 50px;
    }

    .project-desc {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 10px;
        padding: 1rem;
    }

    .projects div {
        flex: 0; 
    }
}
```

```html
<div className='navigation'>
            <div className='nav-item'><Link to='home'smooth={true} offset={100} duration={500}>Home</Link></div>
            <div className='nav-item'><Link to='about'smooth={true} offset={20} duration={500}>About</Link></div>
            <div className='nav-item'><Link to='projects' smooth={true} offset={0} duration={500}>Projects</Link></div>
            <div className='nav-item'><Link to='contact' smooth={true} offset={100} duration={500}>Contact</Link></div>
            <div className='nav-item-resume'><a href={Resume} download>Resume</a></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use media queries for bigger screens.
Basic rule in front-end development today should be to develop websites by mobile-first design. So your CSS file should be mobile-first, then media queries should be using min-width instead of max-width for all bigger screens. If you're using react, you can also check out [React-responsive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive) package.

Also, you can easily check how your website looks in different resolutions by using Chrome's device toolbar (CTRL + Shift + M). You'll have to right click and "Inspect element" first, then use the shortcut. You can type in different resolutions there and cover/check the whole spectre.